# How do I dependent generated values as separate arguments in clojure.spec?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure.spec

I have the following code, I am attempting to use the `path-and-subpath` generator to create values for `(s/fdef conj-set ...)`.

```
(def path (s/coll-of (s/with-gen string? #(s/gen #{"a" "b" "c" "d"}))
                     :min-count 1
                     :kind vector?
                     :into []))

(s/def ::path
  (s/with-gen
    path
    (fn [] (gen/fmap #(vec (take 5 %)) (s/gen path)))))

;; GENERATES THE TUPLES OF PATH AND SUB-PATH
(def path-and-subpath
  (->
   ::path
   s/gen
   (gen/bind
    (fn [xs]
      (gen/tuple
       (gen/return xs)
       (->> xs count inc (s/int-in 1) s/gen))))
   (gen/bind
    (fn [[xs i]]
      (gen/tuple
       (gen/return xs)
       (gen/return (subvec xs 0 i)))))))

(s/fdef conj-set
        :args (s/and
               (s/cat :path <FIRST_VALUE_IN_GENERATED_TUPLE>
                      :sub-path <SECOND_VALUE_IN_GENERTED_TUPLE>)
               #(= (-> % :args :sub-path)
                   (->> % :args :full-path (take (-> % :args :sub-path count))))))
```

I do not know how to put these two things together. I have a generator that generates a tuple, I have a `fdef` with dependent arguments that I want to specify. How to combine them?